# I need iOS screenshots for devices I don't have

Tags: ios, xcode, screenshot

I'm making a sticker pack for iOS, and before I can submit it to the App Store, I need to include at least one screenshot of the app from a 5.5" iPhone, and a 12.9" iPad Pro. These are both devices that I don't have.

I'm also not that well versed in photoshop, but I could learn it as I have read that that's a way to make screenshots to use for the App Store.

Thank You for your help!

Comment: use the Xcode simulator to run your app on any device.

Comment: Use the simulator.

Comment: if you feel one of our answers helped you, please mark it as accepted, otherwise specify why it didn't help, and clarify your expectation. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use simulator. With your app opened in simulator press cmd+S or from menu: File -> Save Screen Shot. Screen shot will appear on your desktop.

UPD: as opposed to https://stackoverflow.com/a/41730054/2305175 you'll get ready to use screen shot with size exactly as in simulator without further work like cropping it

Note: Screenshots resolution is independend of your monitor resolution. So this even works when your monitor has lower resolution than what you need for the screenshot.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot.

Comment: What if I don't even use simulator and will have to build lots of dependency libs for simulator and they don't build with one click, so have to spend some real time to get them built. And this just for the sake of getting high resolution screenshots? Will my app not pass review because of missing screenshots for devices I don't own?

Comment: @rightaway717 Depending on what your libs are you still most likely need to compile them only once for all simulators (x86_64 architecture) which is not that bad. If it takes more than an hours I'd very much like to know what your libraries are. And if it actually takes that long you could just make a simple mock app for screens you'd like to show in app store. You know, use your imagination.

Answer (score 2):

use the Xcode simulator to run your app on any device you don't have. Then take screenshots using Mac OS X built-in screenshot functionality :)

---

P.S. make sure the simulator runs at 1:1 scale (set it in the view menu)

---

@Fydor's apple+s tip sounds way better

Answer (score 0):

The simulator for each device is one option. However, I prefer to use a service for this. I will not plug any services, but google "iOS screenshot service" and take your pick to automate away this process. It should now be part of your app release workflow.